# Displaying Hit and Miss in Array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm looking to display a hit and miss in my java project. Basically, I enter a number and the program either hits or misses. If it hits, it displays a `y`, and if it misses an `x`. From what I've tested in the code, it works, giving the output saying "Hit" or "Try again", but it just doesn't display the x's or y's.

```
public static void displayRiver(int [] river, boolean showShip)
{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("|");
    for (int val : river) {
        switch (val) {
        case -1: // No Ship
            System.out.print("x");
            break;
        case 0: // Unknown
            System.out.print(" ");
            break;
        case 1: // Ship Found
      System.out.print("Y");
            break;
        }//switch
        System.out.print("|");
    }//for


}

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    int userInput;
    int length = promptForInt("Enter the length of the river");
    int riverLength[] = new int[length];
    boolean showShip = false;
    displayRiver(riverLength, showShip);
    int randomShipLocation = new Random().nextInt(length);
    int val;


    while(! showShip)
    {
        val = promptForInt("\n" + "Guess again. ");
        displayRiver(riverLength, showShip);

        if(userInput == randomShipLocation)
        {
            System.out.println("\n" +" BOOM!");
            showShip = true;
            displayRiver(riverLength, showShip);
        }
        else if(userInput != randomShipLocation)
               System.out.print(val);

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't get why you are doing a recursive call of `displayRiver` in case 1.

Comment: sorry just changed that it was supposed to be System.out.print("Y");

Answer (score 1):

The array you pass to `displayRiver` contains only zeroes, since you never change its default values.

Therefore your switch statement always reaches the part the displays empty space :

```
    case 0: // Unknown
        System.out.print(" ");
        break;
```

You should assign `1` or `-1` to the relevant locations of the array based on the user input.

It looks like the loop in the main method should be :

```
while(!showShip)
{
    val = promptForInt("\n" + "Guess again. ");
    if(val == randomShipLocation) // val, instead of userInput
    {
        System.out.println("\n" +" BOOM!");
        showShip = true;
        riverLength[val] = 1; // mark a hit
    }
    else {
        riverLength[val] = -1; // mark a miss
    }
    displayRiver(riverLength, showShip);
}
```

This assumes your `promptForInt` method validates the input (to make sure it is within the range of the array).